# Realizar un input de tipo entrada con button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Espero no suene absurda esta pregunta pero tengo que realizar un input pero sin usar input tengo que capturar unicamente numeros y siempre redondear al mas cerca, puros numeros enteros es decir:
entrada=>149
salida=>100
y realizar los botones que normalmente aparece con un input de tipo number(las flechas de arriba y abajo) pero alado del campo donde ingresamos el numero

[entrada del numero por defecto es 100 y va a ir de 100 en 100 hasta el 500, ya sea que sean digitadas por el usuario][flechas de arriba y abajo estas sirven para cambiar las cantidades antes mencionadas y vayan del 100 al 500 o del 500 al 100 segun el usuario (que no disminuyan o aumenten, simplemente al dar el clcik baje de 100 otro click otros 100 segun sea el caso)]

Se que lo ultimo se puede hacer con js o jquery, pero espero la idea sea entendible.

Answer (score 0):

lo que dices, en efecto la funcionalidad la puedes poner con javaScript, ahora para la conversión de tus numeros, esto te puede ayudar,

```
function redondear(num){var numero=Math.round(num/100)*100;alert("Numero 
redondeado:"+numero)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he entendido lo que quieres es recibir un numero y redondearlo a 100,200,300,400 o 500 y mostrarlo en pantalla. De esta forma puedes conseguir algo parecido a lo que quieres, faltan detalles pero creo que te puede servir:

```js
function redondear() {
var entrada = Math.round(parseInt(document.getElementById("entrada").value));
  if (isNaN(entrada)) {
    entrada = 0;
  } else if (0 <= entrada && entrada <= 49) {
    entrada = 0;
  } else if (50 <= entrada && entrada <= 149) {
    entrada = 100;
  } else if (150 <= entrada && entrada <= 249) {
    entrada = 200;
  } else if (250 <= entrada && entrada <= 349) {
    entrada = 300;
  } else if (350 <= entrada && entrada <= 449) {
    entrada = 400;
  } else {
    entrada = 500;
  }
var p = document.getElementById("p");
  p.innerHTML = entrada;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="entrada" onkeyup="redondear()" value="100" />
<p id="p">100</p>
```